# Visual Studio 2015 CodeLens Github Support

Tags: visual-studio-2015, codelens

Has anybody got CodeLens to work properly with Github?  All of my settings are enabled.  However, I only get reference count for GitHub projects.

[image: CodeLensSettings]

[image: CodeLensView]

Comment: does VS itself show your repo correctly if you go to team explorer?  IIRC, the indicators get the information from the same underlying code that the team explorer does, so if it works in one place, it should work in both.  Also, is this on everything?  or are you only seeing this on new files/new code that you haven't committed yet?
(also, if you aren't using TFS for anything , i'd uncheck all those TFVC ones in your screenshot so they don't get loaded at all)

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling and re-installing VS2015 with Update 2 fixed the issue.  Repairing would not fix, and the update would not fix.  Only uninstalling and re-installing seemed to fix it.

I am not sure if it was because I upgraded from the Community edition to the Professional edition (because I still had Community in my Programs and Features listing).